# count occurences in each dataframe row then create column with most frequent

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I am trying to compare the three floats in a row of a dataframe that is (500000x3), I expect the three values to be the same or at least 2 of them. I want to select the value that occurs the most under the presumption that they are not all different. My current attempt with a toy example is like thus:

```
mydf
   a  b  c
0  1  1  2
1  3  3  3
2  1  3  3
3  4  5  4
3  4  5  5



mydft = mydf.transpose()
    counts=[]
    for col in mydft:
        counts.append(mydft[col].value_counts())
```

I am then thinking of looping over counts and selecting the top value for each but this is very slow and feels anti pandas. I have also tried this:

```
truth = mydf['a'] == mydf['b']
```

with the intention of keeping rows which evaluate to true and doing something to those that do not but I have 1000s of NaN values in the real thing and apparently `NaN == NaN` is `False`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Change the NaNs to None ....doh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use [`mode`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mode.html)...

```
from scipy import stats


value,count=stats.mode(df.values,axis=1)
value
Out[180]: 
array([[1],
       [3],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]], dtype=int64)


count
Out[181]: 
array([[2],
       [3],
       [2],
       [2],
       [2]])
```

After assign it back

```
df['new']=value
df
Out[183]: 
   a  b  c  new
0  1  1  2    1
1  3  3  3    3
2  1  3  3    3
3  4  5  4    4
3  4  5  5    5
```

Comment: mode mode mode God how silly am I to forget that one.

Comment: @Dark I would say coffee help me a lot . :-)

Comment: Perhaps `df.mode(1)`

Comment: @Dark that can achieve it , but I will stack with scipy, in case he need the `count` value :-)

Comment: Wen thats a great one very simple.

Comment: @seanysull yw:-) happy coding

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fast approach I learnt from @coldspeed i.e

```
dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str)).groupby(by=lambda x: x.split('_')[1], axis=1).sum()

df['new'] = dummies.idxmax(1)

   a  b  c new
0  1  1  2   1
1  3  3  3   3
2  1  3  3   3
3  4  5  4   4
3  4  5  5   5
```

**Explanation** :

We can get the one hot encoding of the items present in each column using `pd.get_dummies`, since get_dummies wont take numbers we have to convert them to strings.

```
pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str))

   a_1  a_3  a_4  b_1  b_3  b_5  c_2  c_3  c_4  c_5
0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0
1    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
2    1    0    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0
3    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
3    0    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1
```

Now if you group only the numbers in the column and sum them we can get the value counts for each row. i.e

```
   1  2  3  4  5
0  2  1  0  0  0
1  0  0  3  0  0
2  1  0  2  0  0
3  0  0  0  2  1
3  0  0  0  1  2
```

Using `idxmax(axis=1)` on the one hot encoding will get you the column names which is the required maximum repeated number in the row.

```
0    1
1    3
2    3
3    4
3    5
dtype: object
```

**Edit**:

If you have strings in your dataframe, then go for `get_dummies` that would be faster than anything, if you have numbers then you have to go for `scipy mode` or `pandas mode`

Comment: thanks for the comment but i must admit i dont understand it

Comment: the final result is what i want but im not sure what the matrix above it is, and the command itself also confuses me, I will read up on dummies and try understand your answer.

Comment: Dont worry I shall Explain how this works now :). Give me a minute

Comment: @seanysull read about one hot encoding online. Thats the best I can explain now. Hope it helps. Have a good one.

Comment: Thank you very much I shall read up on it this afternoon hopefully